# zend framework 2 + routing database

Tags: php, zend-framework2

hi have a problemn with zend framework 2 i want a create routing database for example

```
/hello/index => is Application/Controllers/HomeController
/CustomURL => is Application/Controllers/HomeController
```

the CustomUrl i retrieve from database i here is my configuration file

```
  /// module.config.php
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
    .....
  'node' => array(
            'type' => 'Application\Router\Page',//src/Application/Router/Page.php
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/node',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
       ),
     ),....
```

here is my Router class

```
namespace Application\Router;
use Zend\Mvc\Router\Exception;
use Zend\Stdlib\ArrayUtils;
use Zend\Stdlib\RequestInterface as Request;
use Zend\Mvc\Router\Http;
use Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal;

class Page extends Literal
{

  protected $routePluginManager = null;
  protected $defaults = array();

  public function match(Request $request, $pathOffset = null)
  {
      $uri  = $request->getUri();
      $path = $uri->getPath();

      //sample logic here
      //for /about/gallery uri set node id to 1
      //todo: get action, controller and module from navigation        
      if($path == '/node'){
          $uri->setPath('/node/1');
          $request->setUri($uri);

      }


      return parent::match($request, $pathOffset);

  }
  protected function buildPath(array $parts, array $mergedParams, $isOptional, $hasChild)
  {

    if(isset($mergedParams['link']))
    {
        return $mergedParams['link'];
     }

     return parent::buildPath($parts, $mergedParams, $isOptional, $hasChild);
  }
 }
```

im very noob and i need some help for done this part thanks

*** update ***
i want some like post
[Tutorials For Database-Driven Routing in Zend Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382176/tutorials-for-database-driven-routing-in-zend-framework)

Comment: I really didn’t clearly understand what you asked, what i assume is that you are trying to create routing so that if it don't meet your "/node" route it must redirect to some XYZ page?

Comment: yes i want create a routing but by database

Answer (score 1):

My router looks like this:

```
class Content implements RouteInterface,ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{
protected $defaults = array();
protected $routerPluginManager = null;

public function __construct(array $defaults = array())
{
    $this->defaults = $defaults;
}

public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $routerPluginManager)
{
    $this->routerPluginManager = $routerPluginManager;
}

public function getServiceLocator()
{
    return $this->routerPluginManager;
}

public static function factory($options = array())
{
    if ($options instanceof \Traversable) {
        $options = ArrayUtils::iteratorToArray($options);
    } elseif (! is_array($options)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(__METHOD__ . ' expects an array or Traversable set of options');
    }

    if (! isset($options['defaults'])) {
        $options['defaults'] = array();
    }

    return new static($options['defaults']);
}

public function match(Request $request,$pathOffset = null)
{
    if (! method_exists($request,'getUri')) {
        return null;
    }

    $uri = $request->getUri();
    $fullPath = $uri->getPath();

    $path = substr($fullPath,$pathOffset);
    $alias = trim($path,'/');

    $options = $this->defaults;
    $options = array_merge($options,array(
        'path' => $alias
    ));
    return new RouteMatch($options);
}

public function assemble(array $params = array(),array $options = array())
{
    if (array_key_exists('path',$params)) {
        return '/' . $params['path'];
    }

    return '/';
}

public function getAssembledParams()
{
    return array();
}
```

}

I call it this way:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'content' => array(
            'type' => 'Module\Router\Content',
            'options' => array(
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Module\Controller\Content',
                    'action' => 'view'
                )
            )
        )
    )
),
```

In viewAction() in the controller, you can put whatever you want.
I hope this helps.

(I have borrowed this solution frome somebody, but I cannot recall the source anymore. :( )

Comment: I believe it came from here: http://www.zendexperts.com/2012/12/09/custom-routing-in-zend-framework-2/